# Wordpress datepicker pattern in days view

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I am trying to activate the jQuery datepicker in my Wordpress plugin. Any idea where that circle pattern comes from?
Wordpress version 4.9. There are other plugins on the same website using datepicker and they work fine.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BbrV.png)

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a piece of code to test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a CSS issue. It's all but impossible to diagnose without having a code or live sample to look at though.

It seems like like you have CSS added in your plugin or page that's too greedy with it's selector and adding a a background image to the `<td>` elements in the datepicker.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It seems the WordPress Appic theme used by the website is doing that. I changed to a different theme and the datepicker was ok.

Comment: Glad to help! Would you mind accepting the answer if it got you where you needed to be?

Also, if you're able to post a link or copy/paste the relevant HTML, I could attempt to assist you with the CSS issue - it's most likely a simple restructuring of a single CSS selector that too greedily targets `<td>` if you'd like